# Should I check if a key exist before inserting or handle exception on insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception

Which operation is more expensive -- issuing a `SELECT` query before `INSERT`, or handling exception during the `INSERT` operation?

For example, assume I want to persist some user request parameters say `param1`(primary key & unique index), `param2`, `param3` to a database table with a requirement to display a notification if a duplicate key exists already. Furthermore, assume its a real time scenario where the whole process isn't expected to take more than 500ms.

Why is it often recommended to execute insert statement for the three params and then handle insert exception to cater for duplicates? I know that throwing exception has a cost -- does the cost of a database query outweigh that of throwing an exception?

Comment: you could make this question a lot clearer with A vs B code examples.  Even after the revision, I can't picture, in code, what you're trying to describe.  What does "persist parameters to a database" mean?   Insert them into a table?

Comment: Why wouldn't you do both? Preventing exceptions when possible, and handling exceptions when they're possible, are both good practices.

Comment: How often do you expect to try inserting a duplicate? Are the tables properly indexed?

Comment: @TabAlleman yes, insert to a database table using the regular sql `INSERT INTO MyTable(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (param1, param2, param3)`. Now, the above could fail, if a duplicate exists for `param1` in the table. Is it more efficient to first do a `SELECT col1 FROM MyTable WHERE col1='@P1'`, then insert if no duplicate or just insert directly and trap exceptions?

Answer (score -1):

If I insert 1,000,000 times and check first and then insert, that is 1,000,000 checks and say, 957,512 inserts for a total of 
1,957,512 actions against the database. I still have to do something about messaging the user for each of the 42,488 records that fail the intial check.

if I insert and throw an exception I have 1,000,000 actions against the database and 42,488 exceptions to handle.

So the first way of doing business is much more work onteh database.

Comment: I've downvoted this because without any metrics regarding effective time spent detecting duplicate primary keys vs. handling exceptions, I don't think this answer is useful. I strongly expect that detecting duplicates will be far more performant, as that's using the database system as it was designed to be used, and exception handling is notoriously expensive.

Comment: @HLGEM I agree with overslacked. How does the performance compare?